# Change Title of JFrame from other Class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, titlebar

I have two classes, one AnalogClock class and one MainInterface class.

I've created a `timeChanged` method in the AnalogClock class and it gets called whenever the time has changed. My AnalogClock is basically a JPanel with a drawing. In MainInterface I setup a JFrame and add an Object of my AnalogClock.

Is it possible to change the Title of my Window whenever 'timeChanged' is called? I tried to use `getParent()` or `getRootParent()` but they don't recognise `setTitle()`.

Comment: pass reference to `JFrame` and call `setTitle()`

Comment: Which class has the timeChanged method?

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals timeChanged is a method of AnalogClock, and thank you I will try your solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use  [`getWindowAncestor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getWindowAncestor%28java.awt.Component%29)  method from `SwingUtilities`.

```
//This gives you the first Window Object that contains the panel component
Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(panel);

//Cast it to JFrame
JFrame frame = (JFrame) window;

 //Now, change the title
frame.setTitle("New Title");
```

Comment: I get this error 'Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to JFrame' when I use this code: JFrame f = ((JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this)).setTitle(timeToString());

Comment: @ObAt: don't try to squish all the code onto one line, especially when debugging. First get the Window, then try to cast it to JFrame on another line, then set its title on another line. That way when an error occurs, you can see where and how. I'm guessing that your `this` is not a Swing compnent, but who the heck knows? 1+ to rockskull's answer.

Comment: The problem is that `.setTitle("New Title);` returns void.  It's a minor syntax error - I'll fix it.  Basically you don't need to set `f`.

Comment: Ok. I shouldn't put everything into one line. I've been working with ruby and it's kind of a thing there. I have edited the code.

Comment: With what should I replace 'panel'?

Comment: panel is a component which is in the window. Can be a panel, a button, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to pass a reference of the `JFrame` to the `JPanel` and invoking `setTitle()`. Using `getParent()`, you will have identify the proper type of the returned `Container` and then once you've found your `JFrame` reference, cast to it and call `setTitle`.

I usually do it according to the first suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `timeChanged` should be in your `MainInterface` class because `timeChanged` needs to reference both the `AnalogClock` and the `JFrame`. The reason is that your `AnalogClock` probably should not be coupled to your `JFrame`.